# Can "Healing Stone" be used to gain Stamina or Sanity beyond the investigator's initial values?

Tags: arkham-horror

Can the unique item "Healing Stone" be used to gain Stamina or Sanity beyond the investigator's initial values?

The card doesn't include this restriction so I am assuming you can but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your copy of Healing Stone may differ depending on what version of the game and/or which expansions you have. In particular, [Dunwich Horror](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/f2/e7/f2e7b093-5f2c-4dc5-8f9c-b3663580bb59/dunwich_horror_rules.pdf) comes with a new version of this card. 
However, according to the [rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AH_Rules_internat.pdf) (second printing), sanity/stamina as listed on the character's initial values are also their Maximum values. (emphasis mine)

> SANITY AND STAMINA An investigator begins the game with a number of
>   Sanity and Stamina tokens equal to the values listed on the
>   investigator’s sheet. These two values are the investigator’s maximum
>   Sanity and maximum Stamina.
>   **While an investigator may gain and lose Sanity or Stamina over the course of the game, the investigator’s current Sanity or Stamina may
>   never exceed the investigator’s maximum Sanity or Stamina.**

Answer (score 3):

The card may not have that restriction, because it's built into the game itself - a character's sanity and stamina start at the maximum values for that character - while they will go up and down over the course of the game, they can't ever go past that starting, maximum, value unless there you have cards that specifically change this maximum, like Ashcan Pete's Duke.